# Unity iPhone Bundle Identifier has not been set up correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, bundle-identifier

I'm ready to build my game as an iOS app to test on my iPhone, but I keep getting the error:

> iPhone Bundle Identifier has not been set up correctly ... You also
>   have to create a provisioning profile with the same identifier and
>   install it in the Xcode Organizer Provisioning Profiles

My bundle identifier is set up like:

```
com.DrakeTruber.MyGameTest
```

(I'm an individual team: Drake Truber)

I created a provisioning profile matching the bundle identifier above and downloaded it from my Mac Developer site and properly installed it to my Xcode Organizer Provisioning Profiles, yet I *continue* to receive the error when trying to build. What could I possibly be doing wrong, is this a bug? Thanks

Some more (possibly?) relevant information:

- I am using a virtual machine (VMware)
- The project I'm building from is located on my google drive.

[image: Bundle Identifier Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

So far I've seen this error appearing in two cases:

- Either you forgot to add the bundle identifier in the iOS Player Settings in Unity
- Or you entered it, but there might be an empty space in the end that you haven't noticed

You can check that out by going to *Edit -> Project Settings -> Player*, switching to the iOS tab, opening up the **Other Settings** pane and looking for the **Bundle Identifier** field

Comment: I wish this last bullet were the case, but unfortunately the bundle identifier is only comprised of letters and periods. This definitely had crossed my mind earlier though, good point.

Comment: @DrakeTruber hm, weird.. Could you take a screenshot of your player settings and attach it to the question please? Maybe that sheds a light on what's going wrong..

Comment: uploaded screenshot, thanks for your help Peter. The company name is Drake Swartzentruber and the game name is VindacTest

Comment: @DrakeTruber that's weird.. Now I tried it in the same version of Unity that you have with the same data that you used and it seems to work for me. I'm pretty sure you did this several times, but can you clear out that field and type in the ID all over again? Just to make sure? ;)

Comment: Turns out the problem was files in the project folder, deleting all folders but assets resolved the problem